# How to convert local date to UTC?

Tags: date, datetime, momentjs

Can anyone help me with the following:

1. I have am recording date in my UI, which is IST +5:30
2. First, I want to convert that date to UTC with start time 00:00
3. Second, I want to convert that to long time (which I think it is
   Unix)
4. Saved to DB
5. Third, I want to convert a long time back to UTC in format
   MM/DD/YYYY.

This is what I tried so far:

```
const dateUnix => moment(myMomentObj)
  .utc()
  .format(DATE_TIME_FORMATS.TIME_STAMP);
```

The above gets a long time which I don't know if it correct.

```
const dateMoment = moment.unix(dateUnix)
const formatedDate = dateUnix.format('L'); //which should be in MM/DD/YYYY format
```

But the formatDate is giving me something like 02/12/15235 which is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you

```js
//input in IST +5:30
var inputDate = moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format();
console.log(inputDate);

//moment.unix outputs a Unix timestamp
var unixTs = moment.utc(inputDate).unix();
console.log(unixTs);

//there is a unix method that accepts unix timestamps in seconds followed by format to format it
var formattedDate = moment.unix(unixTs).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```